# What were the "mistakes" in the first paperback edition of Ringworld?

Tags: larry-niven, known-space, ringworld

The dedication of [*The Ringworld Engineers*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1299) reads

> If you own a first paperback edition of Ringworld, it's the one with the mistakes in it. It's worth money.

What are these mistakes that were corrected for the second edition?

Comment: Ah yes.. Louis Wu MMGREWPLH, on the twilight of his two hundreth birthday starts his party in Resht.. heading west he goes on to Beirut, Budapest then Munich and finally dials in Sevilla .. where he meets The Puppeteer.. lol. So loved that story.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I remember correctly, the cities that Louis Wu was visiting via transfer booth just before midnight (to keep his birthday going longer) had the Earth rotating in the wrong direction.

Comment: Specifically, Louis Wu is travelling EAST to avoid the sunset -- in later editions of the book, he travels West, which is the correct direction.